# Параметризовать компаратор

Tags: java, generics, hashcode, equals, compare

Вот такую задачку "нарезали", не знаю с какой стороны подойти. Может кто поможет. Необходимо реализовать свой компаратор для обобщенного типа. Думаю как мне может помочь hashcode и equals...

```
public class CollectionUtils implements Comparable, Comparator{

    ......

    //Возвращает лист, содержащий элементы из входного листа в диапазоне от min до max.
    // Элементы сравнивать через Comparable.
    // Пример range(Arrays.asList(8,1,3,5,6, 4), 3, 6) вернет {3,4,5,6}
    public static <T> List range(List<? extends T> list, T min, T max) {
        List<T> newlist = new ArrayList<>();

        return newlist;
    }

    //Возвращает лист, содержащий элементы из входного листа в диапазоне от min до max.
    // Элементы сравнивать через comparator.
    // Пример range(Arrays.asList(8,1,3,5,6, 4), 3, 6) вернет {3,4,5,6}
    public static <T> List range(List<? extends T> list, T min, T max, Comparator comparator) {
        List<T> newlist = new ArrayList<>();

        return newlist;
    }

    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare( Object o1, Object o2 ) {
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Дословная постановка задачи существенно облегчила бы процесс поиска решения. Код полностью ваш или какие-то его части входили в описание задачи?

Comment: Вот вся задача от преподавателя 
    4) Параметризовать методы, используя правило PECS, и реализовать их. 
Я указал те методы, которые не смог параметризовать